Reference: representation theory of the quantum groups $U_q(\mathfrak{g})$ and $U_h(\mathfrak{g})$
I am looking for references where I can find proofs (or at least precise statements) about the following items:

The category $U_q(\mathfrak{g})-\mathsf{mod} $ is semisimple.
The category $U_h(\mathfrak{g})-\mathsf{mod} $ is semisimple.
List all simple, topologically free $U_h(\mathfrak{g}) $-modules.
Are there equivalences of categories between $U(\mathfrak{g})-\mathsf{mod} $, $U_q(\mathfrak{g})-\mathsf{mod} $ and/or $U_h(\mathfrak{g})-\mathsf{mod} $?

Here $\mathfrak{g}$ is a semisimple complex Lie algebra, $U_q(\mathfrak{g})$ is the $q$-deformed quantum group at a generic $q$ (or $q$ not a root of unity) and $U_h(\mathfrak{g})$ is the topological $\mathbb{C}[[h]]$-algebra.
$U_q(\mathfrak{g})-\mathsf{mod} $ (resp. $U_h(\mathfrak{g})-\mathsf{mod} $) stands for the category of finite dimensional (resp. topologically free modules) - possibly of type 1?.
This is a classical topic, but I'm a bit confused: $U_q(\mathfrak{g})-\mathsf{mod} $ has all simple modules of the form $V_{\varepsilon, n}$ with $\varepsilon=\pm 1$ and $n\geq 0$. If I understand correctly type 1 $U_q(\mathfrak{g})$-modules are those with $\varepsilon= 1$, the others seem not to be interesting (why?). The $U_q(\mathfrak{g}) $-modules $V_{1,n}$ can be promoted to simple topologically free $U_h(\mathfrak{g}) $-modules, but do they exhaust all?

The first places where I'd look are the books by Chari–Pressley, Kassel, Lusztig. Are the modules with $\varepsilon =-1$ related to the other ones by a trivial automorphism of the quantum group?

It's common to define category $\mathcal{O}_q$ to contain only the type-1 modules (i.e., we define a weight module to be type 1, and exclude others), since then you get a nice correspondence between the usual category $\mathcal{O}$. If you want to recover the others, pick up the one-dimensional module with the signs you like, and tensor with it.
